# Python unittest gui (output through GUI)

Tags: python, gui, software-testing, unit-tests

Python's unittest framework is command line based. Instead of console output, I'd like to have GUI output. Specific task, that should be accomplishable:

- start all tests per button
- start single test per button
- start group of tests per button
- see output / result inside the GUI

( Kind of like Guitar for GTest in C++ )

Does anyone knows anything?

Searching results in the GUI itself as in "tkinter" for GUI applications.

Answer (score 2):

Cricket does a good job:
[image: Screenshot of cricket]

- Install it:

  - `pip install cricket`
- Navigate to folder, where all your testscripts are.
- run `cricket-unittest`
- You might be requested to install idle-python3.6:

  - `sudo apt-get install idle-python3.6` (for ubuntu)

Source:
https://github.com/pybee/cricket

---

### screenshots:

// test demo use [sanic_security/test/tests.py](https://github.com/sunset-developer/sanic-security/blob/v1.4.7/sanic_security/test/tests.py)

[image: test_result]

[image: fail_detail]

Answer (score 1):

### vscode

those days, vscode also has unittest inside.

#### 1. test pannel:

tests can be run (by click ▶ at right of item) by:

- all
- one folder
- one file
- one class
- one function

[image: test_pannel.png]

#### 2. test result:

errors (and success) can be shown at code side.

[image: test_err_detail.png]

#### 3. outputs

all test outputs

[image: test_output.png]

---

#### which extension?

seems the `testing` (like a flask) icon in side bar appear after `python` extension installed,

if it not exist, <kbd>ctrl+shift+p</kbd> `Python: configure Tests` it will shown.

// make sure `python`,`pip` installed in os
// tested on vscode 1.62 (I didn't see it before)

Comment: seems the `testing` (flask icon) in side bar appear after `python` extension installed